# Doctrine paginator in Symfony2 - how do I use this thing?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know that Doctrine comes with a simple paginator.  Unfortunately, the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) are pretty sparse regarding its use.

How can I use it to show 10 entities per page?  And, does it handle the actual pager functionality, or does it merely implement skip/take functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine paginator is working perfectly well in my case. I have this function in my BaseController (not from Symfony):

```
protected function getDoctrinePaginator(QueryBuilder $qb, $limit=10)
{
    $page = $this->getRequest()->query->get("page", 1) ;
    $qb ->setFirstResult( ( $page-1 ) * $limit)->setMaxResults($limit) ;

    return new Paginator($qb);
}
```

and in template, I have this:

```
{% for user in paginator %}
{{ user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

You have to manually take care of ordering and $page value (read the code) but it is easy to use and unlike knpPaginator, Doctrine works with -big- joins; I have one that has 10-15 joins and few subqueries, works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine pager works perfectly well until you use JOIN statement in your query.

Try using [this jQuery plugin for paging/search solution](http://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: doing this using jQuery is a bad idea. Just think of all the RAM that will die when loading 10 000 + rows from a db when only 25 are needed

Comment: ever heard of AJAX? the plugin works pretty wel loading only needed items. http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: Baiscally saying, implement a paginator on the backend. This is thus not an answer